# Can't get JavaScript output on website

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

The website is supposed to display a message counting down to the tax day. I can't seem to get anything to display on the page. The scrollbar doesn't even show up with the color even though I put in the write code. Some advice please.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>TaxDay</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide from old browsers

function scrollColor() {
 styleObject=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style
 styleObject.scrollbarFaceColor="#857040"
 styleObject.scrollbarTrackColor="#f4efe9"
}


function countDown() {
 var today = new Date()
 var day of week = today.toLocaleString()
 dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
 weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
 newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
 dateLocate = newday.indexOf(",")
 monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate+1)}
 yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2016")
 year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

 var taxDate = new Date ("April 16, 2017")
 var daysToGo = taxDate.getTime()-today.getTime()
 var daysToTaxDate = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24))

function taxmessage() {
 var lastModDate = document.lastModified
 var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
 taxDay.innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:12pt; font-
 family:helvetica;'>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+".
 You have "+daysToTaxDate+" days to file your taxes.</p>"
   }
 }
//-->
</script>
```

The `<div>` id is `taxDay` if it's relevant. The body onLoad event handlers are `scrollColor();` `countDown();` and `taxmessage()`.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't for advice on code. That's what http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for.

Comment: @evolutionxbox True, but the question is actually "why isn't this working", not a request for general advice.

Comment: OP: Please edit your question and text to reflect that you're having a specific issue, and describe the issue completely.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry, I made an assumption based on the title and the large amount of code

Comment: @evolutionxbox An understandable assumption; the question summary and text don't describe the issue/problem well at all!

Answer (score 0):

you are not closing the countdown() function before the taxmessage() function - meaning that taxmessage is nested within countdown(). Also you do not have semicolons ";" after each line of the js. You should rewrite the code to either include the function of taxmessage() or close out countdown() first and call taxmessage with arguments passed to get the date variables.

check your console for errors